# Подключение по Python socket с помощью Ngrok

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

допустим есть вот такой код:

```
server.bind (


    ("3.141.142.211", 1427)

)
```

но данный код не работает, в данной ситуации `3.141.142.211` это `6.tcp.ngrok.io`
но даже если писать напрямую `6.tcp.ngrok.io` код будет выдавать ошибку:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "server.py", line 13, in <module> server.bind ( OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен`

Comment: даже если использовать реальный ип код не работает

Answer (score 0):

bind это чтоб принимать подключения. Принимать их можно в 127.0.0.1 или 0.0.0.0.

Для подключения используйте connect, для сервера на сервере используйте "0.0.0.0" - чтоб можно было подключиться на любой адрес принадлежащий серверу.

Смысл ngrok в том что вы биндите локальный адрес, сервер в интернете биндит адрес который ему принадлежит, а программа ngrok соединяет локальный адрес с внешним.

Comment: разве connect будет работать еще и на сервере? мне кажеться он только для клиента...

Comment: дополнил, 0.0.0.0 подходит для серверов в большинстве случаев

Comment: 0.0.0.0 забиндит сервер на рабочий ипадрес, он не будет работать с ngrok...

Comment: нерабочий адрес не будет работать вообще, не то что с ngrok...

Comment: а 0,0,0,0 работать с ngrok какраз будет, только не забудте запустить клиент ngrok

Comment: если вписать 0.0.0.0 то сервер автоматически забиндиться к ип адресу вашего роутера, и ни о какой работе с ngrok речи идти не может

Comment: Нет, не к роутеру.

Comment: вы пробовали ваше решение? работало ли оно у вас вместе с ngrok?

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать localhost в ip. Порт можно использовать любой. А чтобы запустить ngrok надо прописать ngrok http или tcp и порт. Доступ к серверу можно получить по ip  в консоли.